# A biological process for storing and excreting a fluid at will

Tags: science-based, biology, magic, anatomy, biochemistry

In my world, ingesting a special fluid allows a person to perform magic.

The fluid is powerful and precious in my world, so it cannot be involuntarily excreted from the body in a way that would leave it lying around wherever the person goes. It is critical that the body hold on to the fluid it has absorbed until used.

Even though the fluid is the source of magical effects, it cannot have any impossible properties while it is being processed through the body. The magic begins only at the hands. The fluid must exist in the skin of the hand for the magic to happen.

I am investigating how that this concept could work with real human biology.  I wish that this be based on real biology, or else the point is lost since the whole issue could be just waved away as magic. Unfortunately, presently I cannot think of a good way to make this happen.

Therefore, I wish to know...

**Is there a credible way for an unmodified human to ingest a fluid, store it within the body, and transport it to the hand at will?**

Comment: Comments [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66676/discussion-between-jbh-and-geo).

Answer (score 5):

## The Human Body already has systems for ingesting, moving and excretion fluids

The human body already treats water as a valuable resource that it ingests and only gives up because it has to. This magic fluid isn't poisonous so it can be ingested in arbitrary amounts.

### Pulmonary System

For fluids where high speed of dispersion is important, there's the familiar blood, veins, arteries and heart. If the magic fluid has to get to the hands quickly then the pulmonary systems will do nicely. As long as the magic fluid is fairly close to the viscosity of blood then there shouldn't be any problems moving it around with the normal arteries and veins.

Can this magic fluid get through the stomach and or intestinal lines? Yes? That's your way in. The magic fluid will likely be excreted from the sweat glands when the magician gets nervous.

### Lymphatic System

This system won't concentrate the magic fluid in the hands since the lymphatic system drains to the lymph nodes. I mention it merely for completeness.

(Hilarious that I'm answering this question immediately after donating blood.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the big picture question about magic is 'where does the energy come from?'

Unless you are talking low-energy magic like mind reading or perhaps invisibility, substantial magic like teleportation, levitation, or energy beams takes a lot of energy.

To propose that this energy is somehow produced and stored by and in the body is, well, interesting. There are only a few biological sources of energy - eating, photosynthesis, respiration. I can not imagine that these processes could produce enough energy for serious magic. Some feats of magic would require a miniature nuclear reactor, antimatter reactor, or something of the sort, if the energy were to be internally produced. That is why most magic harnesses external energy supplies.

Since these techniques use processes not natural to the body, I suspect your main worry would be cancer, and other radiation diseases. You would require some serious 'hardening' of DNA and RNA structures, at the least, to protect against the consequences.

Comment: Hi, this answer didn't really address the question, even in its original form. The question was written unclearly so I am putting this comment here to say that although this answer is invalid please don't downvote as it was written in an attempt to address a poorly worded question and as such should not be voted on as being invalid. I would suggests you delete the answer or completely change it to answer the question as it is now which should be much clearer.

Comment: The original question asked for possible implications on the body. Cancer is still, even in the new question, a concern. Anything non-natural introduced to the body presents a cancer risk.

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the approach of side-effects? I mean,  some meds we take can cause some pretty strange side-effects.

People become sleepy, some might have memory problems,  you name it.

You could make it so that a simple cold would cause your wizards to blow up things by accident, or because they can't pronounce their spells properly they could make their neighbors vanish.

Some problems like anemia could make them unable to levitate anything metallic...

Think of what kind of illnesses are caused by what or cause which symptoms and use that.

A Witch/wizard with a sunburn would be incapable of lighting a fire by using magic...

There is so much to use. I don't think you need a profound knowledge in biology.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of examples exist in molecular biology for specific substances being processed within cells, if the receptors exist on the exterior of the cell (e.g. antibiotics specifically docking to the exterior of bacterial cells or neuro-receptors in the human brain where drugs like nicotine may interfere).

You want a magical fluid which stores the compound. When an ordinary human drinks the fluid it will pass through his body without interaction of the magical compound, but your wizards have been genetically engineered or mutated to have the receptors for the substance. These receptors would be located in a 'magic gland' only wizards possess.

Consider your magical process as a metabolical cascade fueled by the cell's energy production ATP -> ADP. Like other processes in our body, such cascades can be triggered as soon as the cell receives the 'message' to start processing the 'magical metabolic'.

To make this process thought triggered, your wizards would need to have a direct link of their gland to the neural system and the 'magic gland' cells require neuroreceptors to be activated by thought processes.